# How do we not allow hard tabs in my codebase? We are using JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint

How do we not allow hard tabs in my codebase? We are using JSHint.

I think smarttabs only disallows mixed tabs on the same line.

What option should we be using to achieve this?

Comment: JSHint is removing **code style** related options [in the next major release](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#indent) and recommends checking out [the JCSC project](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs) for enforcing code style rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSCS [validateIndentation](http://jscs.info/rule/validateIndentation) is the relevant option. It corresponds to the (deprecated) JSHint [indent](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#indent) option.