# How do I disallow tabs in JavaScript via jshint or jscs?

Tags: javascript, jshint, jscs

I'm setting up enforcement of style rules for a JavaScript project and I'd like to disallow tabs in files altogether (favoring two spaces per indent level). The only related jscs option I've found is [disallowMixedSpacesAndTabs](http://jscs.info/rule/disallowMixedSpacesAndTabs), which doesn't disallow tabs completely.

Comment: I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897776/how-do-we-not-allow-hard-tabs-in-my-codebase-we-are-using-jshint but decided to open this question because that one is specific to jshint.

Comment: How about having the build script just egrep the sources for tab characters?

Answer (score 0):

JSCS [validateIndentation](http://jscs.info/rule/validateIndentation) is the option I was looking for. It corresponds to the (deprecated) JSHint [indent](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#indent) option.